# No GPS onLocationChanged callbacks while app in background?

Tags: cllocationmanager, android-gps

I have a working app that processes and logs GPS positions using the LocationManager's onLocationChanged() callback. It works fine *until I put the app in the background*, e.g. by going to another app using the "Recent Tasks" button or Home button. Updates resume when I bring it to the front again. Interestingly, I do see status changes from GPS "Temporarily Unavailable" to "GPS Available" when brought to front. I do check "isProviderEnabled()" while in background but it always returns *true*.

I see no mention of this artifact in the LocationManager doc: **maybe this is an undocumented but intended behavior (???)**

- I tried implementing GPS listener as a service. No joy.
- Then I tried spawning an ASyncTask inside Service (including GPS listener on service start). Still no joy.

In either case, same behavior: onLocationChanged not called when app that started Sevice goes to background.
Anybody have a suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: I need to use a *Foreground* Service.
This is described in https://androidwave.com/foreground-service-android.example
With this change, GPS fixes are then received even after main activity is stopped (finished).